# Android - Cannot allign two buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a form using LinearLayout. All the objects appear fine, except for two buttons.
I'm trying to align them in a there own LinearLayout, but for some reason one of them is always lower than the other.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.InviteMember"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_invite_member">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout1">
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Invite Team Members"
    android:id="@+id/invitememebrsView"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/invitememberLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Enter Team Member Email"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/memberemail"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/createteamLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="8"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="             mycool@emailaddress.com"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,@,."
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/editemailaddress" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Phone Number"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="85dp"
        android:id="@+id/memberphonetextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/invitememberLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:hint="                    Only digits allowed"
        android:id="@+id/memberuserphonenumber" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Invite Member"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/createteamLayout2"
        android:id="@+id/invitebtn"
        android:onClick="onInviteMember" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/Donebtn"
        android:onClick="onDonebtn"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:id="@+id/Exitbtn"
    android:onClick="onExitbtn"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the UI**
[image: As you can the 'Exit' button is not aligned with the 'Done' button]

Comment: set orientation = horizontal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bcz you have defined orientation to vertical.

**Replace this code in your XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.InviteMember"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_invite_member">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invitememebrsView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/invitememberLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Invite Team Members"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/memberemail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/createteamLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Enter Team Member Email"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editemailaddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,@,."
            android:hint="             mycool@emailaddress.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lines="8"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/memberphonetextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/invitememberLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="85dp"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/memberuserphonenumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="                    Only digits allowed"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/invitebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/createteamLayout2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="onInviteMember"
            android:text="Invite Member" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Donebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDonebtn"
            android:text="Done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Exitbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onExitbtn"
            android:text="Exit" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And it's Done.**

Comment: @DavidFaiz Glad to help you :).

Comment: Hey,
I've encountered a similiar issue with an ImageView, is there a chance you can take a look?

Comment: @DavidFaiz What is the problem ?

Comment: I've added an image, but it does not align with the button next to it.
In addition, I would like to know how can I place the LinearLayout they are located in below another LinearLayout.

Comment: Discard my request Jay, I took another look at you solution here and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you gave the `LinearLayout` which contains the buttons a **vertical** orientation, change it to **horizontal**

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `LinearLayout` which contains the 2 buttons -

replace -

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

with

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Because you want your buttons to be arranged horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Orientation in LinearLayout means One after another

So don't use orientation vertical in last LinearLayout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:id="@+id/Donebtn"
            android:onClick="onDonebtn"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:id="@+id/Exitbtn"
        android:onClick="onExitbtn"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or other way you can do this is to change `LinearLayout` with buttons with `RelativeLayout` like that

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Donebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onDonebtn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Done"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Exitbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onExitbtn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Exit"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in last linearlayout which contain done and exit . set -

```
android:orientation="Horizontal"
```

let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:orientation="horizontal"` in last LinearLayout. And If you want to align these two buttons left and right side I suggest you to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout4"
  android:weightSum="3">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Invite Member"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/createteamLayout2"
    android:id="@+id/invitebtn"
    android:onClick="onInviteMember"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Done"
    android:id="@+id/Donebtn"
    android:onClick="onDonebtn"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:id="@+id/Exitbtn"
    android:onClick="onExitbtn"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```